# Popover flash in child component, VueJs and BootstrapVue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I try to use a popover in a child component, but it behaves strangely . It flashes (activate / deactivate ) on each 2ms like a flash.

```
<statistic-row :popover_text="'Text example.'" />  //this if from parent

<template>
  <b-row>
    <b-col xl="4" md="4" sm="4" xs="4">
      <h5>
        <span v-show="popover_text" v-b-popover.hover.top="popover_text">
          <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>
        </span>
      </h5>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["popover_text"]
};
</script>
```

Comment: I think it might be because of the content of your span. Could you try replacing your Icon with normal text to see if it still happens?

Comment: Another note, you don't need to specify a value for each breakpoint. Bootstrap breakpoints counts for everything above. So if you set `sm="4"`, that will count for `sm` and above. I also don't think there's a `xs` prop, It's called `cols`.

Comment: I didn't expect this. But with a p tag works, you can submit the answer, thank you! Also for the tip!

Comment: Also I just saw that if I remove " .top " works for spam too.

Comment: What version of `Bootstrap-Vue` are you using? It could be a problem that has been fixed if you're on an older verison.

Comment: It's not the last one. I am using 2.7.0 , the latest is 2.14.0.

Comment: what is the value of popover_text ?